# log in adb shell "interactive mode" and "non-interactive mode"

Tags: adb, iperf

I'm writing script to run iperf on linux device accessible via adb.

1. From a terminal, when I run the command: *adb shell iperf -c ......*
   I get the log of the command 50 s after the command starting.
   **inconvenient**: during 50 s you are not sure that iperf has started
   I tried the logcat command (*logcat --pid ...*), It gives the same result.
2. From a terminal, when I enter adb session first and then I run the command: *iperf -c .....*
   I get the log of the command in real time.
   **inconvenient**: I'm not able to automate the procedure, because I have to start the adb session first

For the first use case: Is there a way to force "log flush" in order to get the log in real time?
For the second use case: Is there a way to send commands to already opened adb shell session?

Is there any other ways to launch iperf on device and get the log in real time?

Answer (score -1):

The solution i found is the library pexpect that allow to interact with adb session.